# jQuery scrollTop doesn't scroll the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried using `e.preventDefault();` and `return false;` at the end of the code those didn't help. Here is my code:

```
$('.game-nav-inner-game1 .nav-item a').click(function (){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".scrollHere").offset().top - 100
    }, 400);
});
```

And this is my html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs game-nav game-nav-inner game-nav-inner-game1-events" data-game="game1" data-container="events-container">
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#nameofthemap" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="nameofthemap">
        <img src="{$smarty.const.SITE_ADDR}/resources/img/game1-game/maps/nameofthemap.jpg" class="img-fluid game1-map" />
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content w-100">
   <div class="tab-pane fade scrollHere" id="events-container"></div>
</div>
```

The

I would appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: Where is the element with class name 'scrollHere'?

Comment: Right below the `<ul>` tag. I updated my post. Sorry for missing this.

Comment: Did you check whether you receive the click event in the handler? The scrolling code appears to be fine.

Comment: There is no `.game-nav-inner-game1`... Try with `$('.game-nav-inner .nav-item a')`

Comment: Also, the click event handler looks wrong. it should be `$('.game-nav-inner-game1 .nav-item a').click(function (){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".scrollHere").offset().top - 100
    }, 400);
});`

Assuming `.game-nav-inner-game1` class exists.

Comment: Yes it exists. The problem is not the html but the jquery function.

Comment: You say you tried with `e.preventDefault();`... Did you pass the `e` as argument? like: `.click(function(e){` ?

Comment: Yeah, I did that.

Comment: @nived, class `game-nav-inner-game1-events` exists, but I can't find `game-nav-inner-game1` in your provided HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you are posting, I added a wrapper `div` with class `game-nav-inner-game1`, since you confirm it is supposed to exist.

And some "spacer" divs...

```js
$('.game-nav-inner-game1 .nav-item a').click(function (){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".scrollHere").offset().top - 100
    }, 400);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="game-nav-inner-game1">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs game-nav game-nav-inner game-nav-inner-game1-events" data-game="game1" data-container="events-container">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#nameofthemap" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="nameofthemap">
        <img src="{$smarty.const.SITE_ADDR}/resources/img/game1-game/maps/nameofthemap.jpg" class="img-fluid game1-map" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div style="height:150em;"></div>

<div class="tab-content w-100">
 <div class="tab-pane fade scrollHere" id="events-container">HERE</div>
</div>

<div style="height:150em;"></div>
```

Run the snippet... You'll see that it is working, actually. So your problem is with selectors... Or something else like a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript Vanilla [`Element.scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). Your snippet (simplified for focus reasons) would look like:

```js
$('.click-here').click(() => $('.scroll-here')[0].scrollIntoView(true))
```

```css
body {
  height: 1500px;
}

.scroll-here {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="click-here" href="javascript:void(0)">Click here</a>
<div class="scroll-here">Scroll here</div>
```